# Memory leakage C++ threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks, parallel-processing, stdvector

I have a problem, probably, with memory leaking in C++ threads. I receive a runtime error with code 11. I am writing an optimization algorithm, which aims to optimize parameters of 2D reactors. It generates instances of reforming function, which creates Reformer objects. The reformers have 2 different parameters, which can differ locally in a single reformer and are passed to the reforming function from the main function. To specify, each reformer is divided into a specified number of zones (same dimensions and locations in each reformer), and each zone can have different parameters. Therefore, size of each of 2 vectors is equal to [NUMBER OF REFORMERS] * [NUMBER OF ZONES]. Then, the reforming function creates Segment objects, which number is equal to the number of zones.

I assume that the issue here is that threads try to access the same vector simultaneously and I would really appreciate a solution for that matter.

Remarks:

1. If I change the main.cpp to substitute the threads with a usual loop, no error is returned.
2. If I comment out the setProp method in the set_segments functions, no error is returned (with threads).

Threads are highly recommended here, due to long computation time of a single Reformer, and I have an access to a multi-core computing units.

To clarify, I will explain everything with a minimal reproducible example:

input.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
int reactor_no = 2;    // number of reformers
int zones_X = 5;       // number of zones in a single reformer, X direction
int zones_Y = 2;       // number of zones in a single reformer, Y direction
double dim_X = 0.5;    // reactor's length    
double dim_Y = 0.2;    // reactor's height
double wall_t = 0.1;   // thickness of the reactor wall
size_t zones = zones_X * zones_Y;
```

Reformer.h:

```
#include "input.h"
class Reformer {
public:
    Reformer() {}
    Reformer(const double& L, const double& Y, const double& wall_t, 
                        const int& zones_X = 1, const int& zones_Y = 1) {
        length_ = L;
        height_ = Y;
        zonesX_ = zones_X;
        zonesY_ = zones_Y;
        wall_thickness_ = wall_t;   

        dx_ = length_ / static_cast<double> (zonesX_);
        dr_ = height_ / static_cast<double> (zonesY_);
    }

private:
    double wall_thickness_;         // wall thickness (m)
    double length_;                 // recactor length (m)
    double height_;                 // reactor height (m) (excluding wall thickness)
    int zonesX_;                    // number of segments in the X direction
    int zonesY_;                    // number of segments in the Y direction 
    double dx_;                     // segment width    (m)
    double dr_;                     // segment height (m)
}
```

Segment.h:

```
#include "input.h"
class Segment{
public:
    Segment() : Segment(0, 0) {}

    Segment(int i, int j) {
        i_ = i;
        j_ = j;
    }

    void setXR(const double& dx, const double& dr, const int& SL, const int& SR) {
        x0_ = i_ * dx;
        x1_ = x0_ + dx;

        r0_ = j_ * dr;
        r1_ = r0_ + dr;

        if (i_ == SL - 1) {
            x1_ = length;
        }

        if (j_ == SR - 1) {
            r1_ = radius;
        }   
    }

    void setWall() {
        x0_ = 0;
        x1_ = length;

        r0_ = radius;
        r1_ = radius + wall_t;
    }

    void setProp(const double& por, const double& por_s, const bool& cat) {
        porosity_ = por;
        catalyst_ = cat;
    }
private:
    size_t i_;          //segment column no.
    size_t j_;          //segment row no.

    double x0_;         //beginning of segment - x coordinate (m)
    double x1_;         //ending of segment - x coordinate (m)
    double r0_;         //beginning of segment - r coordinate (m)
    double r1_;         //ending of segment - r coordinate (m)

    int catalyst_;      //1 - catalytic, 0 - non-catalytic
    double porosity_;   //porosity (-)

};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "input.h"
int main() {

    int zones = zones_X * zones_Y;

    size_t pop_size = reactor_no * zones;
    std::vector<int> cat;
    cat.reserve(pop_size);
    std::vector<double> porosity;
    porosity.reserve(pop_size);                // the values in the vectors are not important, therefore I will just fill them with 1s
    for (int i = 0; i < pop_size; i++) {
        cat[i] = 1;
        porosity[i] = 1.0;
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> Ref;
    Ref.reserve(reactor_no);
    for (k = 0; k < reactor_no; k++) {
        Ref.emplace_back(reforming, k, cat, porosity);
    }

    for (auto &X : Ref) { X.join(); }
}
```

reforming.cpp:

```
    #include "input.h"

void reforming(const int m, const std::vector<int>& cat_check, const std::vector<double>& por) {                                           
    Reformer reactor(length, radius, wall_t, zonesX, zonesY);

    std::vector<Segment> seg;     // vector holding segment objects                                                                  
    seg.reserve(zones);

    set_segments(seg, reactor, zones, m, por, por_s, cat_check);

}
```

set_segments function:

```
#include "input.h"
void set_segments(std::vector<Segment> &seg, Reformer &reac, const int m, 
                     const std::vector<double> &por, const std::vector<int> &check) {
    int i, j, k, n;

    double dx = dim_X / static_cast<double> (zones_X);
    double dy = dim_Y / static_cast<double> (zones_Y);

    std::vector<Segment*> ptr_seg;
    ptr_seg.reserve(zones);

    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < zones_X; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < zones_Y; j++) {
            n = m * zones + (i * zones_Y + j);
            seg.emplace_back(Segment(i, j));
            seg[k].setProp(por[n], check[n]);
            seg[k].setXR(dx, dy, zones_X, zones_Y);
            k++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Memory leaks shouldn't produce runtime errors. And where is your `main` function?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov, I'm not a C++ wizard, so I don't know if "runtime errors" has some special, narrow meaning of which I am unaware, but a program can't go on leaking memory forever. _Some_ bad thing must eventually happen.

Comment: @Padzak, There might be somebody here who could offer help if only they knew what "code 11" means. Could you add the full text of the error message to the question, and maybe also tell us what Operating System was running the program and what tools you used to build it?

Comment: What is `spec_max` and why do you reserve just `reactor_no == 2` threads?

Comment: I apologize for inconsistencies, I am self taugh and still struggle a little sometimes. I am using CLion and code 11 was returned by the IDE. Two threads are just an example, in the original code I generate 30 threads.

Comment: @Padzak If you know the number of threads you should reserve at least this number of elements in vector. Otherwise why to reserve?

Comment: Don't include from the `main` function!

Answer (score 0):

Adding std::ref() to the reforming function call parameters solved the problem.

```
for (k = 0; k < spec_max; k++) {
        Ref.emplace_back(reforming, k, std::ref(cat), std::ref(porosity));
}
```